# Global HotKeys in Win&X11

Tags: python, hotkeys

I need to make a global hotkey for my application, and it should work under X11 and Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What GUI toolkit are you using? Generally, global hot keys are handled by the Desktop environment or Window Manager - I dont believe that Python's builtin toolkit (tkinter) can make global hotkeys. You might look at [xlib](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) for Unix and a win lib for windows.

Comment: I use Qt (PyQt).
So, for different OS i should use different libraries?

Comment: I think so. As an alternative, you might check out QXT (addon for qt) which has this cross platform global shortcut class http://docs.libqxt.org/0.4.0/classQxtGlobalShortcut.html

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition - on windows, if you are using wxpython in your application, you can register your [hotkey](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#RegisterHotKey).
Example is [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/RegisterHotKey)